# Using Touch ID in custom app - Only 5 users?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, ios8

Ok, I understand that starting iOS 8, we can use Local Authentication framework to utilize already stored finger prints on device to login to the application. Now, does this mean that only 5 users can use my application using finger prints (Touch ID)? What if a device is being shared by more than 5 people? Anyone tried this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can register 5 fingerprints in a iOS device with TouchID. These could be five different people or 5 different fingers for the same person or any combination of that, but only 5 fingers in total.

iOS devices don't have any concept of 'users' - they are intended as 'personal' devices - so the local authentication framework doesn't provide any user identifier - just whether the authentication was successful or not.

In short, only 5 fingers (people in your case) can be enrolled for TouchID - any others would need to use a passcode fallback

Comment: While I agree with your explanation, I was building an iOS application that will be running on a shared device which will be used by multiple people. I saw an [interesting post][1] claiming to add more than 5 finger prints.


  [1]: http://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-add-more-than-five-fingerprints-to-iphone-5s-touchid/

Comment: You are still only adding five "fingerprints" you are just relying on the recognition code being able to match based on a single read rather than average reads. The other problem with this approach is that to delete a user you need to get all of the other people in that "slot" to re-enroll